# Edit is persisting another entity but is not setting on it

Tags: java, jpa

I have a werid problem with JPA:

I have an entity and I just added a relation with other entity, so when I edit the first entity the another object must be persisted and set on the first entity updating it.

By example

Company is the first entity, and I just added the manager entity, so my Company now has a new field named "manager" with a relation to managers table (Many to one since that manager can manage 1 to many companies).

In my class definition with this scenario I have this:

Company.java:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "manager", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Manager manager;
```

Manager.java:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "manager")
private List<Company> companies;
```

So I set the new manager to some company, when I do an edit via remotefacade the new manager is created but is not being set in the previous company.

Some weird is I have not the cascade.persist annotation anywhere but is being persisted on edit.

Somebody can help me :) ?

Edit:

This is how I set the manager to a company:

action.java

```
Manager m = new Manager();
... (set all the data)

Company c = companyFacade.find(1); // find by ID

c.setManager(m);

companyFacade.edit(c);
```

Comment: Post some code here, particularly that code for edit method.

Comment: Hi, the edit method is the generated by netbeans when you generate  session beans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys thanks for read and answer this question.

The problem was a "detach" that I forgot in the find method at early development. Now it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the code where you associate the manager to the company? Please note:

- You also have to associate the company to the manager: E.g. manager.addCompany(company)
- Are you certain that your mappedBy attribute is set properly? Is there a setAsistente method on the Company class?

Comment: Hi! "assistente" is not an attribute, was a mistake. I just edited :)